# Is there any appstore with an API?

Tags: api, app-store, google-play, amazon-appstore

I want to read app names and reviews from an appstore. Can be any appstore: Apple appstore, Google market/play, Amazon... Anyone aware of any appstore that exposes a public API for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to fetch Data from the Apple AppStore. The page returns all information about the app in JSON, so you simply have to decode the output:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close')));
$inh = file_get_contents("http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsLookup?id=$appid&country=us");
$inh = json_decode($inh);
$rs = $inh->results["0"];
$ituneslink = $rs->trackViewUrl;
$price = $rs->price;
$appname = $rs->trackName;
$screens = $rs->screenshotUrls;
...
```

Be sure to insert the App-ID.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to search for apps? will apple throttle this and block me after some quota?

Comment: No searching for Apps is not possible with this "API", I think. To your second question, you can access this as often as you want. I have an App-Review website which works with this and every call this executes the above code a few times, and it always worked well.

Comment: Is that official API? I would like to use to compare versions and recommend update. That is why i need to be sure Apple won;t disable it.

Comment: actually it's the official API, I think. Or at least there isn't any other official API.